# Using example ncurses code, but need clarification

Tags: refresh, ncurses

I'm compiling some c code using the ncurses library, under gcc and Fedora.  The code is copied exactly from http://techlister.com/linux/creating-menu-with-ncurses-in-c/1293/

It compiles fine but as I manipulate the code I wanted to understand some of ncurses' subtleties - specifically, its screen refresh scheme. I've read in multiple places (this site and elsewhere) statements such as:

> The refresh and wrefresh routines (or wnoutrefresh and doupdate) must be called to get actual output to the terminal, as other routines merely manipulate data structures.

I interpret that as meaning if I call things like mvwprintw(), I am only manipulating what amounts to a virtual window, and to get my changes to actually appear, I need to call wrefresh(). However the code I copied only calls wrefresh() once near the top and seems to repaint the screen as needed.

QUESTION: Can some one clarify when one should need to call refresh() or wrefresh()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other **`wrefresh`** is happening in this line

```
  while(( ch = wgetch(w)) != 'q'){
```

because (as noted in the [**`wgetch`** manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters)):

> If the window is not a pad, and it has been moved or ***modified*** since the
>   last call to **`wrefresh`**, **`wrefresh`** will be called before another character
>   is read.